# weblogic 11g R1

Tags: deployment, weblogic

I have prepared my ejb jars and war using weblogic.appc 
weblogic 11g R1, all compilations were fine, I have prepared ear and deployed in weblogi server .I am getting belows erorr. afte deployment and ear status went to failed state.

I am not att all using this oracle.help.OHW file. don't know it is refered

Can any suggest how comeout of this problem.

[HTTP:101216]Servlet: "OHW" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "cbcm". javax.servlet.ServletException: [HTTP:101249][ServletContext@13514259[app:cbcm module:cbcm path:/cbcm spec-version:null]]: Servlet class oracle.help.OHW for servlet OHW could not be loaded because the requested class was not found in the classpath . java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.help.OHW. at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:551) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205) at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:140) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `web.xml` within your WAR, there is a `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` for the Oracle help files and this servlet most likely.

Comment out those.

Comment: thanks for your reply. you have correctly told the problem , I added library to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
I received the same error as "failed to preload on startup in Web application:".

Below is how I am able to resolve the error.

in your web.xml, check if following property is present

<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>

this property is to load your bundled artifacts during the server restart itself. This was the cause of the issue because there were some jar file which weblogic server required to load before the loading of our bundled artifacts. Now since server is not yet started completely and all the libraries required to our application is not yet loaded, hence server is throwing "failed to preload on startup in Web application:".

The solution to this is remove load-on-startup from web.xml and That's it!!
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, albeit very late, have solved the issue with JoseK answer